# How to get tweets from twython?

Tags: python, twython

I'm building a bot that searches for a word in a tweet and then replies to it.

This is how far I got:

```
from twython import Twython

CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""

OAUTH_TOKEN = ""
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ""

twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN,    OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

status = twitter.show_status(id="562590793391542272")

message = "hello"

twitter_id = 562590793391542272
```

How can I get the id of a tweet with a keyword?
For example the last tweet with the word "dog" in it?

I have tried streaming/searching and everything, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

I am really not certain what you're accomplishing or what you're trying to accomplish with your above code, but I you can accomplish getting the tweet id of the latest tweet with `stackoverflow` via:

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError


app_key = 'your_app_key'
app_secret = 'your_app_secret'
oauth_token = 'your_oauth_tokem'
oauth_token_secret = 'your_oauth_secret'

twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

search_results = twitter.search(count=1, q='stackoverflow')

try:
    for tweet in search_results['statuses']:
        print 'Tweet ID: ', tweet['id']
except TwythonError as e:
    print(e)
```